# A,B are diagonalizable matrix and their characteristic polynomials are the same.prove that $A$ and $B$ are similar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

let A,B are diagonalizable matrix in ${c^n}$ and  their characteristic polynomials are the same. can we prove that $A$ and $B$ are similar?

Comment: Hint: the characteristic polynomial is the product of ...

Answer (score 2):

By assumption, $A$ is similar to $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}\alpha_1&0&\cdots&0\\0&\alpha_2&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\cdots&\cdots&\vdots\\0&\cdots&\cdots&\alpha_n\end{array}\right)$, and hence its characteristic polynomial is given by$$f_A(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n(x-\alpha_i).$$The matrix $B$ is similar to a diagonal matrix with $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n$ on the diagonal, and hence$$f_B(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n(x-\beta_i).$$Since the two polynomials are assumed to be the same, we have that $(\alpha_i)$ are the same as $(\beta_i)$, up to reordering, and the two matrices are indeed similar.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ and $B$ have same eigenvalues and hence same diagonal matrix $D$. Let $A=PDP^{-1}$ and $B=QDQ^{-1}$ where $P$ and $Q$ are invertible (just using change of basis concept). Thus we have $D=P^{-1}AP$. Substituting, $B=QP^{-1}APQ^{-1}=(PQ^{-1})^{-1}A(PQ^{-1})$ . Taking $PQ^{-1}=S$ we get $B=S^{-1}AS$ and hence similarity follows.

Comment: Assuming $P,Q$ orthogonal is wrong. (And irrelevant.) Not every diagonalisable matrix is orthogonally diagonalisable.

Comment: You may assume they are unitary. That will do the same thing.

Comment: Same difference. Unitary is wrong and irrelevant. And not every diagonalisable matrix is unitarily diagonalisable.

Comment: Okay to be very very safe, here is a final answer.

Comment: Definitely better. But now I see that you are simply assuming $A,B$ to be similar to the _same_ diagonal matrix, but that is essentially assuming the conclusion of the question (that $A,B$ are similar to each other). The point is to give an argument deducing this from equality of the characteristic polynomials (which hypothesis you never even mention).

Comment: I do not understand. Reordering the diagonal elements in the diagonal matrix i.e. reordering the eigenvalues is premultiplication and postmultiplication by some elementary matrices again, which do not affect similarity.

Comment: @yedaynara As you wrote your answer, all you need is the first line up to the first period: if $\;A,B\;$ have same eigenvalues and both are diagonal then they're similar. Finish. What did you write all the rest for?? In fact, what's interesting here, I guess, is to deduce that since we're working with matrices over an algebraically closed field and they both have the same char. polynomial, then their eigenvalues (i.e., their char. pol's roots) are exactly the same, and these will appear in the diagonal of their Jordan...etc. You're assuming the OP already knows all the above in first line.

Comment: Ok I now see where the confusion is. Thanks for pointing out. Anyway my learned colleague has already posted an answer which I find caters to this need.